# Web applications for mobile devices?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-website

What is the best way to develop a web-application for mobile devices?

1- Do you create different pages and redirect users based on the operating system?

2- Do you modify the same web-page to re-size itself and fit well on mobile devices?

3- I've seen that some web-applications look very similar to native applications, what does it take to achieve this? (Date pickers, table views, spinners, etc)

Comment: for third question: Checkout jQuery mobile framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done it as option1 with jQuery framework. Just created views but used most of the existing business logic. It is working as expected.